# Is there a way to show activation function in model plots tensorflow ( tf.keras.utils.plot_model() )?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The model plot in TensorFlow shows the shape of input, dtype and layer name. Is there some way to show the type of activation function as well?
If there is some other better way of showing/plotting the neural networks please tell.

Comment: Yes. define it as a layer: .`tf.keras.layers.ReLU`

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a way, if we can add the activation function beside the input and output, rather than creating a new layer.

Comment: There is no such config in `plot_model` function to show activation function besides layer info. However, if you want to show an arbitrary text, you may concat activation function of each layer to it's name: `name = "layer_1: relu"` or you may use other tools such as [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron), which shows activation functions.

Comment: @Kaveh `layer_1: relu` maybe not a valid layer name, use `layer1_relu` instead.

Comment: @C.K. Yeah, you're right. It can not be any string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the tensorflow version solved the *'Error: bad label' issue* when setting both show_shapes and show_layer_activation to True for me. (TF Version 2.8.0)
Update tensorflow version with

```
pip install -U tensorflow
```

plot model call

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_activations=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.utils.plot_model()` has an argument `show_layer_activations` which adds the name of the activation function for each layer in the plot:

```py
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_layer_activations=True)
```

However, I get an error if I set both `show_shapes` and `show_layer_activations` to true:

```py
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_activations=True)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvocationException                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-12b331a03265> in <module>()
----> 1 keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_activations=True)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pydot_ng/__init__.py in create(self, prog, format)
   1889             raise InvocationException(
   1890                 'Program terminated with status: %d. stderr follows: %s' % (
-> 1891                     status, stderr_output))
   1892         elif stderr_output:
   1893             print(stderr_output)

InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Error: bad label format conv2d|{Conv2D|relu}\n|{input:|output:}|{{(None, 28, 28, 1)}|{(None, 26, 26, 32)}}
Error: bad label format conv2d_1|{Conv2D|relu}\n|{input:|output:}|{{(None, 13, 13, 32)}|{(None, 11, 11, 64)}}
Error: bad label format conv2d_2|{Conv2D|relu}\n|{input:|output:}|{{(None, 5, 5, 64)}|{(None, 3, 3, 128)}}
Error: bad label format dense|{Dense|softmax}\n|{input:|output:}|{{(None, 1152)}|{(None, 10)}}
```

So maybe using the layer name to indicate the activation function is the better way (at the moment).

Comment: i got the same error, did you find any solution and reason?